# Two Factor Authentication using Google Authenticator in own asp.net project?

Tags: asp.net, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Hello I have created own asp.net project (Not MVC). Now I want to implement Two Factor Authentication using Google Authenticator. So when ever user get register user will get key or get QR image and setup with it's android phone. And for login they need key from google authenticator app.

I got few MVC code in asp.net. I need steps to how integrate in asp.net application (Not MVC) Please guide how can i implement this any sample will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Scott hanselman has a tutorial for that: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingTwoFactorAuthenticationToAnASPNETApplication.aspx

Comment: @S_I_R Thanks But it should work With Google Authenticator App.

Comment: here is the your perfect answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368154/how-to-make-google-authentication-scan-qr-code/47368506#47368506

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368154/how-to-make-google-authentication-scan-qr-code/47368506#47368506

Answer (score 6):

To Add Google authentication you need the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;
using Google.Authenticator;
```

To get the Google.Authenticator; check here https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAuthenticator

now setting up the Google authentication.

```
TwoFactorAuthenticator tfa = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();
var setupInfo = tfa.GenerateSetupCode("Name of the app", "More info ABout the App", "SuperSecretKeyGoesHere", 300 , 300//the width and height of the Qr Code);

string qrCodeImageUrl = setupInfo.QrCodeSetupImageUrl; //  assigning the Qr code information + URL to string
string manualEntrySetupCode = setupInfo.ManualEntryKey; // show the Manual Entry Key for the users that don't have app or phone
Image1.ImageUrl = qrCodeImageUrl;// showing the qr code on the page "linking the string to image element"
Label1.Text = manualEntrySetupCode; // showing the manual Entry setup code for the users that can not use their phone
```

you can change the `SuperSecretKeyGoesHere` to any value that you want, but make sure it has more than 10 character otherwise the manual entry key that is generated will not work.
Now you can check the user input with text box and button click

this bit will look at the user entry and see if its ok

```
string user_enter=TextBox1.Text;
TwoFactorAuthenticator tfa = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();
bool isCorrectPIN = tfa.ValidateTwoFactorPIN("SuperSecretKeyGoesHere", user_enter);
if (isCorrectPIN == true)
{
Label2.Text = "i am cool";

}
else
{

Label2.Text = "i am Fool";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I've blogged about your case exactly, you can read the post: [Two Factor Authentication in ASP.NET Web API & AngularJS using Google Authenticator](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/15/two-factor-authentication-asp-net-web-api-angularjs-google-authenticator/)
Hope this answers your question.